# AWS DMS Error - Unable to use plugins to establish logical replication on source PostgreSQL instance

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, dms

I'm getting this error trying to replicate a postgre database (not RDS) to another postgre database (also not RDS). I get this connection error but the endpoints (source and target) are tested successfully. Any ideas?

Error: Last Error Unable to use plugins to establish logical replication on source PostgreSQL instance. Follow all prerequisites for 'PostgreSQL as a source in DMS' from https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/userguide/CHAP_Source.PostgreSQL.html Task error notification received from subtask 0, thread 0 [reptask/replicationtask.c:2880] [1020490] Remaining 1 error messages are truncated. Check the task log to find details Stop Reason FATAL_ERROR Error Level FATAL

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 6):

I used DMS to reduce over-provisioned RDS storage size.
Set following values in db parameter group in both source and destination endpoints and restart. Maybe this will help for non-RDS endpoints if you add the same in Postgres configuration.

```
logical_replication = 1
max_wal_senders = 10
max_replication_slots = 10
wal_sender_timeout = 0
max_worker_processes = 8
max_logical_replication_workers = 8
max_parallel_workers = 8
max_worker_processes = 8
```

Answer (score 3):

You need at least to set `logical_replication = 1` in your source database configuration.
And then set the `max_replication_slots = N`, `N` being higher or equal to the number of replication processes you plan to run.

Answer (score 1):

I have this problem with setting up the `ongoing replication` at the AWS DMS migration task.

I change the `source` and `target` endpoint `Parameter groups` setting below:

```
session_replication_role = replica
rds.logical_replication = 1
wal_sender_timeout = 0
```

and keep the remaining setting as the default

```
max_replication_slots = 20
max_worker_processes = GREATEST(${DBInstanceVCPU*2},8)
max_logical_replication_workers = null
autovacuum_max_workers =  GREATEST({DBInstanceClassMemory/64371566592},3)
max_parallel_workers = GREATEST(${DBInstanceVCPU/2},8)      
max_connections = LEAST({DBInstanceClassMemory/9531392},5000)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to [follow all the steps](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/userguide/CHAP_Source.PostgreSQL.html#CHAP_Source.PostgreSQL.Prerequisites.SelfManaged) in the guide that is displayed in the error. You need to update `pg_hba.conf` to allow the DMS instance to access. E.g. if the private IP on the DMS instance is on the `10.6.x.x` range:

```
host    your_db         dms             10.6.0.0/16             md5
host    replication     all             10.6.0.0/16             md5
```

Then you'll need to create a `dms` [user](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/sql-createuser.html) and [role](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createrole.html) with superuser privileges.

Then follow the guide to update `postgresql.conf` with the wal settings, e.g. `wal_level = logical` and so on.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this by granting the source database user the right access roles on the pglogical schema

```
grant usage on schema pglogical to <replication user>;
grant select on all tables in schema pglogical to <replication user>;
```